# Drupal 6 + Jquery File Upload - Content-Type application/json for Ajax call

Tags: jquery, drupal

Ajax/Jquery is not really my area of expertise...
I'm trying to use the excellent Jquery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) with Drupal 6. Implementing a working code on a Drupal page doesn't work and I'm pretty sure the problem is with the content type returned by the ajax call.

The call looks like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: fileupload_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');

        });
    },
});
```

Outside of Drupal the Content-Type of the request is set to "application/json" but on a Drupal page it's "text/html; charset=utf-8".

I've been Googling trying to find a solution but even though I see a lot of topics discussing this sort of thing I'm not sure how to implement a solution.

If anyone can, please show me how

TIA

Comment: Send out new headers from your drupal controller that say `header('Content-Type: application/json');`?

Comment: Thanks you Ohgodwhy, I did try adding that on the page the #fileupload div is in but then the page won't load as it needs the utf-8 content type. Any chance you can tell me how to do this only for the POST in the Ajax call?